# What does the -b option do when using the `at` command, if anything?

Tags: man, at

According to [`man at`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at), one of the ways to call `at` (version 3.1.10 on my system) is with the form:

> **at** [**-V**] [**-q** *queue*] [**-f** *file*] [**-mldbv**] *time*

Although **-m**, **-l**, **-d**, and **-v** are all documented, nowhere can I find an explanation as to how the **-b** flag is actually used. My original intuition was that it might allow access to `batch`, similar to the **-l** and **-d** options, which provide alternate ways to access `atq` and `atrm` respectively.

On attempting to test this theory to see if it would just put a job into the "b" queue that `batch` uses, I tried running `at -b now + 1 hour`, but this fails right away with:

> at: invalid option -- 'b'

Perhaps **-b** only works when given with certain other options, or perhaps I'm misinterpreting the man-pages somehow. Any insights into this?

Comment: My local man page lists it as `-b      is an alias for batch`

Comment: @MichaelHomer did you check to see if it was it lying?

Comment: It still doesn't work, but it's what the documentation says. `at -b` is listed separately.

Answer (score 3):

`at -b` is supposed to be equivalent to `batch`, but there's a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812972): `b` isn't declared in the [list of valid options](https://sources.debian.net/src/at/3.1.18-2/at.c/#L749), so [`getopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) reports an error and `-b` isn't actually processed.

If you add `b` to the list of options, then [it's handled correctly](https://sources.debian.net/src/at/3.1.18-2/at.c/#L838) and `at -b` becomes equivalent to `batch`.